# Max length sending JSON to an ASP.NET MVC Action

Tags: json, json-deserialization, maxlength, json-serializable

When I try to send the list of more then 400 records (each won't have more than 900 char length). After setting the maxJsonLength property to its maximum value in web.config still not getting any error. 
When I try to send the list of less then 30 records. It works perfectly.

Comment: <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000">
        </jsonSerialization>
      </webServices>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<scripting>
  <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000">
    </jsonSerialization>
  </webServices>
</scripting
```